# Rails Netzke v0.10.1 - Refreshing grid panel within a tabpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

I try to make a Netzke component with one master grid and subgrids in the south region of a Panel.
When a row in the maingrid is selected then should the subgrids be filtered with records related to the record in maingrid -  like described here for an old netzke version:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/netzke/tabpanel/netzke/PFAQ-wYyNog/2RJgRLzh80oJ

I know that netzke is not further in development but I use it in a project.

- ruby 2.1.2 (Mac OSX rbenv)
- rails 4.0.10
- netzke-core v0.10.1
- netzke-basepack v0.10.1

Here my Code:

models:

```
class MbOrganisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :mb_contacts

  def customer_name
    "#{orga_customer} - #{orga_name1}"
  end

end



class MbContact < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :mb_organisation

end
```

This is the  central component
app/components/organisation_multitab.rb

```
class OrganisationMultitab < Netzke::Base

  component :organisation_organisations

  component :organisation_tabpanel do |c|
    c.klass = MblixBaseTabpanel
    c.items = [:organisation_contacts]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.layout = :border
    c.border = false

    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function(){
        // calling superclass's initComponent
        this.callParent();

        // setting the 'rowclick' event
        var view = this.netzkeGetComponent('organisation_organisations').getView();
        view.on('itemclick', function(view, record){
            // The beauty of using Ext.Direct: calling 3 endpoints in a row, which results in a single call to the server!
          this.selectItem({item_id: record.get('id')});
        }, this);
      }
    JS

  end

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.items = [
        { items: [:organisation_organisations], region: :center },
        { items: [:organisation_tabpanel], region: :south, height: 200, split: true }
]
  end

  endpoint :select_item do |params, this|
   # store selected id in the session for this component's instance
    component_session[:selected_item_id] = params[:item_id]
  end

end
```

These components are additionally used
Maingrid - organisation_organisations.rb

```
class OrganisationOrganisations < Netzke::Basepack::Grid

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = "MbOrganisation"
    c.columns = [:orga_customer, :orga_name1, :orga_name2, :orga_street, :orga_zip, :orga_city, :orga_tel, :orga_email]
    c.force_fit = true
  end
end
```

Component with Tabpanel- base_tabpanel.rb:

```
class BaseTabpanel < Netzke::Basepack::TabPanel

  component :organisation_contacts do |c|
    c.data_store = {auto_load: false}
    c.scope = {:mb_organisation_id => component_session[:selected_item_id]}
    c.strong_default_attrs = {:mb_organisation_id => component_session[:selected_item_id]}
  end

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.active_tab = 0
    c.prevent_header = true
  end

end
```

The grid component for the contacts:

```
class OrganisationContacts < Netzke::Basepack::Grid

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = "MbContact"
    c.columns = [{ :name => :mb_organisation__customer_name,
                   :header => "Organisation"
                 }, :cont_salutation, :cont_title, :cont_lastname, :cont_firstname, :cont_email, :cont_tel, :cont_mobile, :cont_birthday]
    c.force_fit = true
  end

end
```

The function `this.selectItem(...)` is correct triggered and calls the endpoint in OrganisationMultitab.

**I have two problems/questions**

**First** 
*- How can I automatically reload the stores of the subgrids in the tabpanel?*

The described way in the linked google groups article: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/netzke/tabpanel/netzke/PFAQ-wYyNog/2RJgRLzh80oJ is outdated (It's for netzke v0.5 - I use netzke v0.10.1):

```
{
        :south => {

          :item0 => {:load_store_data => aggregatee_instance(:south__item0).get_data},
          :item1 => {:load_store_data => aggregatee_instance(:south__item1).get_data}
        }
}
```

second problem: I got an error - when I manually refresh the subgrids:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in NetzkeController#direct
```

**Update**

The `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` is solved by myself. There was a bug in the netzke-basepack gem:

`Netzke::Basepack::Grid` ran in an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (rails 4 strong parameters) when the component, like above described, has a scope configured. (config[:scope] will later be merged to the params object that is an ActionController::Parameters object. - As the scope is database related this will be denied with `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` )
My solution: In the `endpoint.rb` the ActionController::Parameters will be converted to a Hash - then the error is gone.

*I made a fork and a pull request in github for this gem.*

**But**

the second problem is not solved.

**second** problem: *Now the subgrids can be manually refreshed without an error but they are always empty.*

I guess the scope in the child component

```
  component :organisation_contacts do |c|
    c.data_store = {auto_load: false}
    c.scope = {:mb_organisation_id => component_session[:selected_item_id]}
    c. strong_default_attrs = {:mb_organisation_id => component_session[:selected_item_id]}
  end
```

has no access to the value of the

`component_session[:selected_item_id]`

of the Organisation MultiTab parent component?

But it is neccessary to split the components - like described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/netzke/tabpanel/netzke/sDrU7NZIlqg/-2wGmed7fjcJ

Hope there is somebody who can help me. :-)

Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` because you're not `permit`ing the attributes from the controller. Rails now uses [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) instead of `attr_accessible` (like in Rails 3).

Comment: I know that rails 4 uses strong_parameters but in normal case netzke does not use databsae related parameters. My second problem, i've described above was a bug in the netzke-basepack gem: Grid ran in an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when the component has a scope configured. (config[:scope] will later be merged to the params object that is an ActionController::Parameters object. - As the scope is database related this will be denied with ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)
solution: convert ActionController::Parameters to a Hash - then the error is gone-made a pull request for this

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution by my self.

**First** issue - *reloading the grids in the Tabs*

The store of the Ext gridcomponent can also be accessed in the Javascript.
So I extended the Javascript configuration of the OrganisationMulitab with this part:

```
Ext.each(this.netzkeGetComponent('organisation_tabpanel').items.items, function(item, index) {
     item.getStore().load();
});
```

**Second** issue - *send the selected id to the scope in the child component*

The value must be sent to the session of the child component - so this does the job:

```
 component_instance(:organisation_tabpanel).component_session[:selected_item_id] = params[:item_id]
```

instead of

```
component_session[:selected_item_id] = params[:item_id]
```

(The problem with the `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` was a bug in the gem - solution is in my update of the question - I made a fork of the gem https://github.com/tomg65/netzke-basepack/tree/master-fixes-changes and sent a pull request to the original https://github.com/netzke/netzke-basepack/pull/158)

**So the final code looks like this** and all works fine:

```
class OrganisationMultitab < Netzke::Base

  component :organisation_organisations

  component :organisation_tabpanel do |c|
    c.klass = MblixBaseTabpanel
    c.items = [:organisation_contacts]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.layout = :border
    c.border = false

    c.init_component = <<-JS
      function(){
        // calling superclass's initComponent
        this.callParent();

        // setting the 'rowclick' event
        var view = this.netzkeGetComponent('organisation_organisations').getView();
        view.on('itemclick', function(view, record){
          // The beauty of using Ext.Direct: calling 3 endpoints in a row, which results in a single call to the server!
          this.selectItem({item_id: record.get('id')});
          Ext.each(this.netzkeGetComponent('organisation_tabpanel').items.items, function(item, index) {
            item.getStore().load();
          });
        }, this);
      }
    JS

  end

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.items = [
        { items: [:organisation_organisations], region: :center },
        { items: [:organisation_tabpanel], region: :south, height: 200, split: true }
    ]
  end

  endpoint :select_item do |params, this|
    # store selected id in the session for child component's instance
    component_instance(:organisation_tabpanel).component_session[:selected_item_id] = params[:item_id]

  end

end
```

Hope this helps others too.

Best regards

Thomas